# VisualStudio2010: AccessViolationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, exception

I get an *AccessViolationException* when I try to start debuggin a C#-MVC2-webproject in VisualStudio 2010. But there is no Stacktrace or indication where the error occurs.

When I switch from *degub-mode* to *release-mode* I get the error "unknown software error" (0xe0434352) [...] at (0x765e5b727). The window has the title from the ASP.NET Development Server.

How can I find the bug in my code to remove it???

Thanks!
Tobi

Comment: Is it just this specific project? What happens if you create a new ASP.NET MVC 2.0 project using the template from scratch? Do you get the same exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled VisualStudio 2010 and finally it works fine - no Exception anymore.